# How to make an event trigger itself again on getting an Exception?

Tags: java, events, jsch

I have a java swing App that connects to a remote Unix box using JSch.

The user needs to provide the ip of the unix box in a JTextBox in the Swing App and clicks a "LOGIN" button in the App.

I need to prompt the user to enter another ip if there is some problem with the connection.
For this I catch JSchExceptions and prompt the user to enter a valid ip again....  And then after the user enters another ip, I try to login again..

My Code is working fine till prompting the user to enter the ip again on getting a JSchException... But I am not able to trigger the ActionEvent again to initiate the login process again...

I used `button.doClick();` on the LOGIN button, but the event is not trigerring again as excepted !!

i also tried to do this after seeing some examples online:

```
ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent((Object)button, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(ae);
```

Still not working !!!

What could be the problem ? How can I make the event trigger itself again ??

Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to reset the variables for next trial. It would be better if you post part of the code executed when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Alper.. There are no variables as such to be reset.. The only input I take is the ip which I prompt the user to enter... The Event Handler takes the input directly from the Swing App.. 
After the user enters the ip, i update the required data and I want to retrigger the ActionEvent again which is not happening !!!